# WTSSendmessage before stopping a service

Tags: c, winapi, service, windows-services, window

Am trying to display a message box once the user tries to stop a service.

For this I used `WTSSendmessage` API... And I called the function once the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` event occurs..

Am I right in the above step?? Because am not getting a message box once the user trie to stop the service..

Please guide me...

Below is my code snippet::

```
case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
    WTSSendMessage = (fptr1)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "WTSSendMessage");
    BOOL ret = WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwSession, lpszTitle, 12 ,lpszText, 7 ,MB_YESNO|MB_ICONINFORMATION, 0, &res, TRUE);

    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
    SetServiceStatus( serviceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus );
    SetEvent( stopServiceEvent );
    return;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the "dwSession" variable is set correctly? What is its value?

Comment: dwsession is set to "DWORD dwSession = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();"

Comment: hi coretech, the problem is with "dwsession".. I replaced "dwsession" with "WTS_CURRENT_SESSION". "WTS_CURRENT_SESSION" is defined as "#define WTS_CURRENT_SESSION ((DWORD)-1)". but the same code is not working in windows 7.. any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() as described in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg465093) I showed you in your earlier question. That article includes all the code you need.

I also urge you to include error checking for your API calls. Diagnosing errors without that help is harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Hi David, I used BOOL ret = WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), (LPWSTR)L"WARNING", 8*2 ,(LPWSTR)L"My warning message", 74*2 ,MB_ICONERROR|MB_TOPMOST|MB_SETFOREGROUND, 0, &res, FALSE);" , by using its not running in xp even?? any idea?