# presponse parameter WTSSendMessage

Tags: c, winapi, service, windows-services

I'm involved in writing a service and I'd like to diaply a message box on "service stop request"..

I tried using "WTSSendmessage" API.. But that didnt display a message box.
My another doubt is what should be the input for "Presponse" parameter in  WTSSendmessage.

Is there any examples??

Comment: Repost of your previous question. Look at the answers there: [WTSSendmessage before stopping a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634450/wtssendmessage-before-stopping-a-service)

Answer (score 1):

Presponse is a pointer to a variable that receives the user's response. Means the button which the user press.

```
    typedef BOOL (*TypeSendMessage) ( HANDLE,DWORD,LPWSTR,DWORD, LPWSTR, DWORD, DWORD,DWORD, DWORD*, BOOL);

   TypeSendMessage SendMessage;
   HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"Wtsapi32.dll");

 if(hModule)
 {
   ////////////////// WTSSendMessage ////////////////
   SendMessage = (TypeSendMessage) GetProcAddres(hModule,
                 "WTSSendMessageW");
   if(!SendMessage) 
          return FALSE;

   DWORD res;
   SendMessage( WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
               WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), (LPWSTR)L"Title", 5*2,
               (LPWSTR)L"Sample Message",14*2, MB_ICONERROR| MB_TOPMOST|MB_SETFOREGROUND,
               FALSE,    &res,  0);
 }
```